# How to create and interaction between google drive and aws s3?

Tags: amazon-s3, web-applications, google-drive-api

I'm trying to set up a connection a Google Drive folder and S3 bucket, but I'm not sure where to start. 
I've already created a sort of "Frankenstein process", but it's easy to use only by me and sharing it to my co-workers it's a pain.

I have a script that generates a plain text file and saves it into a drive folder. And to upload, I've installed Drive file stream to save it in my mac, then all I did was create a script using Python3, with the boto3 library, to upload the text file into different s3 buckets depending on the file name.

I was thinking that I can create a lambda to process the file into the s3 buckets but I cannot resolve how to create the connection between drive and s3. I would appreciate if someone could give me a piece of advise on how to start with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you just simply want to connect google drive and aws s3 there is one service name zapier which provide different type of integration without line of code

```
https://zapier.com/apps/amazon-s3/integrations/google-drive
```

For more details you can check this link out

Comment: Yes, I saw it. The thing is that the S3 service is not free. Also I've tried it, but as far I can see this just saves it in a bucket but ignores if there are subfolders in it.